# A way of injecting TestNG test parameters into custom method invoked by IInvokedMethodListener

Tags: java, testng

@BeforeMethod can have Object[] parameter which is injected with parameters which are supplied to test method

```
public class SampleTest {

@DataProvider
public Object[] one(){ return new Object[]{ 1 };}

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp(Object[] params){
    Assert.assertEquals(params[0], 1);
}

@Test(dataProvider = "one")
public void test(Integer intParam){
    //test smth
}
}
```

I want to inject such parameters to my custom method which is invoked by IInvokedMethodListener

```
public class MethodInGroupsListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {

@Override
public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod iInvokedMethod, ITestResult iTestResult) {
     Method customMethod = /* code to find my method */
     Object[] params = /* this is where help is needed */
     customMethod.invokeMethod(iTestResult.getInstance(), params);
}
```

The question is how can I do this?

Comment: what is the signature of the custom method ? Does it access Object [] ?

Comment: It has the same signature as @BeforeMethod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestNG now provides a new listener called `IDataProviderListener` which is invoked before and after dataprovider is called. Using this we can get the dataprovider method and save it as a static method (Dataproviders are called before all configuration and test methods). This dataprovider method can be later invoked to get the run time Object[] value in the `beforeInvocation()` method.

Not the cleanest of solution but it can get the job done and could be a good starting point to further enhance.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.testng.IDataProviderListener;
import org.testng.IDataProviderMethod;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethod;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener2;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestNGMethod;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class CustomListen implements IInvokedMethodListener2, IDataProviderListener {

    private static Method savedDataProviderMethod = null;

    @Override
    public void afterDataProviderExecution(IDataProviderMethod dataProviderMethod, ITestNGMethod testNGMethod, ITestContext context) {
        System.out.println(">> afterDataProviderExecution start");
        savedDataProviderMethod = dataProviderMethod.getMethod();
        System.out.println("<< afterDataProviderExecution end");
    }

    @Override public void beforeDataProviderExecution(IDataProviderMethod dataProviderMethod, ITestNGMethod testNGMethod, ITestContext context) {}

    @Override public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {}
    @Override public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {}
    @Override public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult, ITestContext context) {}

    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult, ITestContext context) {
        System.out.println(">> beforeInvocation start");
        // Method customMethod = // code to find custtom method;
        try {
            Object[] params = (Object[]) savedDataProviderMethod.invoke(testResult.getInstance());

            for (Object param : params) {
                System.out.println("Dataprovider return data --" + param);
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // customMethod.invokeMethod(testResult.getInstance(), params);
        System.out.println("<< beforeInvocation end");
    }
}
```

Tested on **TestNG 6.14.3** on below test class

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ABCTest {
    @DataProvider
    public Object[] one() {
        return new Object[] { 1 };
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp(Object[] params) {
        System.out.println("setUp execution");
        Assert.assertEquals(params[0], 1);
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "one")
    public void test(Integer intParam) {
        System.out.println("test execution");
    }
}
```

Gave output of

```
-------------------------------------------------------
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
>> afterDataProviderExecution start
<< afterDataProviderExecution end

>> beforeInvocation start
Dataprovider return data --1
<< beforeInvocation end
setUp execution

>> beforeInvocation start
Dataprovider return data --1
<< beforeInvocation end
test execution
```

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer. This seems like valid solution.